# check if a list subset of another list (values can be repetative)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sublist

I am trying to check if the list `List2` is a subset of `List1` in python 3.8

I tried `all()` and `issubset()` functions and they all fail to filter it as I wanted - they give True, unfortunately - elements of `two` actually not all in `one`, are they?

```
List1 = [1,  4, 1, 3, 5]
 
List2 = [1 , 1, 1]
```

What I tried:

```
check =  all(item in List1 for item in List2)
```

failed, returns True.

```
flag = 0
if(set(List2).issubset(set(List1))): 
    flag = 1
print(flag)
```

failed, returns True.

Also using `intersection()` gives True (actually I don't want intersection).

What is the solution for this? Have not checked `Numpy` yet.

Comment: Every element of `List2` is in `List1`, so the attempts that return true are correct. If you actually want to check *counts* of elements, then try using Counters.

Comment: Yes i was escaping from counting but I must use a counter i thnik that will be the most reliable thing.. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Counter

```
from collections import Counter 
  
def is_second_list_in_first(first_list, second_list): 
    ' checks if 2nd list of elements is in first list of elemetns with sufficient counts  '
     # get counts of two lists
    count_first = Counter(first_list) 
    count_second = Counter(second_list) 
  
    # check if count of elements exists in first list
    return all(count_second[key] <= count_first[key] for key in count_second)
    
# Tests
print(is_second_list_in_first([1,  4, 1, 3, 5], [1]))        # True
print(is_second_list_in_first([1,  4, 1, 3, 5], [1, 1]))     # True
print(is_second_list_in_first([1,  4, 1, 3, 5], [1, 1, 1]))  # False
```

Answer (score 0):

This probably isn't a great solution, but you can brute force this with:

```
def sub_list_check(main_list, sub_list):
    elm = 0
    last_elm = len(sub_list)-1
    for x in main_list:
        if x == sub_list[elm]:
            elm += 1
            if elm > last_elm:
                return True

        else:
            elm = 0
    
    return False
```

This is assuming the exact order of your sublist, List2, matters. i.e. this won't check for reversed order.

If you are only asking whether or not List2 elements are contained with List1, then use sets. If number of items matters, then you can't use sets and you could use something like Counter() from the collections library.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks,

I had to search a little bit more i think.

numpy **isin()** method did not work but this one looked ok.

```
import numpy

arr = numpy.array([1,  4, 1, 3, 5])

print([1 , 1, 1] in arr.tolist())
```

However first I need to sort the arrays i think... not sure